# Как программно установить любое окно поверх других?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

Как я могу установить окно **любого** чужого процесса, зная его ID, поверх других окно, при том чтобы оно было поверх - постоянно?

Хочу это сделать на C#, наверное используя Winapi

Comment: SetWindowPos, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683330/how-to-make-a-window-always-stay-on-top-in-net

Answer (score 2):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
const UInt32 SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;


public void ShowWindowByProcessId(int _processId, string _machineName)
{
    var process = Process.GetProcessById(_processId, _machineName);

    IntPtr windowHandle = process.MainWindowHandle;
    SetWindowPos(theWindowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
}
```

[Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528473/make-a-window-topmost-using-a-window-handle)

Comment: Когда окно теряет фокус, оно снова становится не поверх других. Можно ли этим способом установить, чтобы окно было постоянно поверх других?

Comment: Я пробовал на windows 10, окно остается поверх других  окон после потери фокуса. В тоже время, возможен случай когда окно будет перекрыто другим окном, при потере фокуса, это возможно если у другого окна Topmost-true. В таком случае все будет зависеть от фокуса.

Comment: В качестве решения можно скрыть другие окна, или сделать их не topmost.